# passing $(this) from function to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different event on different classes :

```
$('.box1').click(function(){
$(this).find('something').css('red')
}

$('#otherId .box2').change(function(){
$(this).find('something').css('red')
}
```

But I plan to split them out to a function to avoid duplicate code

```
function getDetails(this){
  this.find(".something").css('red');
}
```

but how to call the function later? pass the $(this) to the function?

```
$('#otherId .box2').change(function(){
getDetails($(this))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is a keyword so it can't be a param name

```
function getDetails(el) {
    el.find(".something").css('red');
}

$('#otherId .box2').change(function () {
    getDetails($(this))
})
```

Comment: is this better than using call()?

Comment: Both are the same... but I prefer to pass it as a param than changing the execution context

Comment: I see. This is easier to understand too.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` can't be used as an argument, but you can keep using `this` within the function body:

```
function getDetails()
{
    $(this).find(".something").css('red');
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
$('#otherId .box2').change(function() {
    getDetails.call(this);
}
```

See also: [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: @zerkms that's what she said ... just woke up, couldn't resist ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to pass it through if you want to get an inputs value then change it and output the final value next to it:

```
var finalOutput;

function getDetails(args) {
    args = "Hello World";
    return args;
}

$('.box2').change(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    finalOutput = getDetails(inputValue);

    $('.box2').after('<b>' + finalOutput + '</b>');
});
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/La4v9mL0/